# Incompatibilidade nos navegadores

Tags: html5

Estou desenvolvendo um site usando html e css com bootstrap. Já havia notado algumas pequenas diferenças entre um navegador e outro.

Mas essa semana após usar algumas imagens svg, no internet explorer desconfigurou tudo! Eu já uso um arquivo css reset, o que não tem nada haver com isso certo?

Gostaria de saber além de uma solução para o uso do arquivo svg no internet explorer, como posso tornar uma coisa aparecendo igualmente em todos os navegadores?

Comment: Cara vc pode usar o normalizer eh meio chato de implementar, mas eh uma forma de tratar o crossbrowser. Outra coisa que vc pode fazer eh usar polyfills e a at rule @support de uma pesquisada sobre isso aqui no site e no google. E lembre-se que nem todo browser da suporte ao svg, e menos ainda ai propriedades do svg v2.0 pesquise sobre isso tb

Comment: Os "resets" ajudam note que o Bootstrap já tem seu próprio "reset" más, alcançar **100%** de igualdade visual em todos os diferentes navegadores não é viável.

Comment: Oi meu amigo. Cara, muito obrigado mesmo! Vou aqui começar a pesquisar sobre as coisas que colocou aqui. Valeuzão!!!!!!!!!!